How can I make my camera see everything I drew?
How can I make my camera see everything I drew?
I drew something. Now I want to make it a jpg. Now I understand I must first render the image. but when I do that my camera doesn't see everything I drew. How can I make my camera see everything I drew?
I tried everything like selecting camera, trying to move it, grab it, transform etc, it is extremely counterintuitive and I cannot do it.
All I want is to print what I drew, so all I want is my camera to see everything I drew. how can I do that. Is there an automatic way to do it?

Not being able to do something as simple as transform the camera is symptomatic of doing basically no research. If this isn't a transform problem, you've provided pathetically little information about your scene to go on. How did you "draw something"? What tool did you use? What do you mean by "my camera doesn't see everything I drew"? Is part of the drawing out of frame, or just invisible, or what? You should have at least two images, a screenshot of your 3D scene, and the render result.

Your question is not clear at all. At least add a screenshot of Blender's window so that we can see what you're doing!

With the Camera selected, hit N to show the side panel. Then select the View tab and check the Camera to View checkbox under View Lock. You can now drag things around and zoom in and out with the scroll wheel until you get the view you want to render.

The Blender manual section on Camera Positioning is here.
Don't forget to turn it off when you have finished.

Thanks i appreciate

An easy way to do intuitive camera transformations is to aim your viewport at the drawing, and then use Align Active Camera to View, accessed by default with Ctrl + Alt + Numpad 0, or 3D Viewport -> View -> Align View.
If this ends up being too close, you can move the camera back by setting the Transform Orientation to Local, and then moving the camera along its local Z axis. You can do this "in third-person" with the 3D Viewport Move tool, or in "first-person" Camera View by pressing G then Z and moving your mouse (click to confirm).
Note that if parts of your drawing are just plain invisible in render but not in 3D Viewport, despite being in the camera's frame of view, there's a good chance you've used Annotations by mistake. Annotation does not show up in renders. What you want to use for render-able drawings is Grease Pencil.

Ctrl-Alt-Numpad0
showes nothing now. first it was showing like most of my drawing. no annotations used i drew it properly.

You have to aim your view at the drawing first.

yes, how? i am switing back and forth between camera view and general view. carrying camera around at all axis, including writing coordinates too . i need an automatic way for camera to see everything i drew which should just position the camera to all i drew

With the Camera selected, hit 'N' to show the side panel. Then select the 'View' tab and check the Camera to View checkbox under View Lock. You can now drag things around and zoom in and out with the scroll wheel until you get the view you want to render.

@JohnEason that is a separate answer to achieve a similar result. Please post it as such.

As in, look at the drawing. Like, orbit, pan, and such in the 3D Viewport so the drawing is in view. You say you can see your drawing, yes?

@JohnEason your answer, view lock was the key. Thanks it works, i can manipulate the object in camera view as I want like this. Yes, as thelabcat said, if you write this as answer, i can select it as solution.

Ok. Now added as an answer. Probably a good idea to put that option on the Quick Favorites Menu.
